# What's the Laravel equivalent of index?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to run something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table USE INDEX (index)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

```
Post::from(DB::raw('posts force index (key)')->...
```